# why does Ubuntu 17.04 slow down?

Tags: 16.04, performance, 17.04

I installed 17.04 Ubuntu a week ago, it is working very slowly it makes angry but I love Ubuntu. Please give me a suggestion. if increase 4GB to 6 GB. will it be okay?

- Computer: Hp elite book
- RAM: 4GB
- HDD: 320 GB

I run four application whole day (STS, skype, hubstaff, browser).

Comment: Define _slowly_. The question is too broad and very vague. Please add more details

Answer (score 1):

- Open the Dash and search for system monitor. Go to process tab and see which process is taking up CPU/Memory (by clicking on CPU/Memory tabs). If its taking high cpu/memory for long period, kill it and check if system is fine. Mostly its because of some rogue process
- Do you have any graphics card ?

Comment: i do not have graphics card.  only use for programming java.

Comment: sts software takes 2GB.

Comment: okay but i heard ubuntu is very fast. even RAM is low . my friend says . it is very slow why?.

Comment: if increase 4GB to 6 GB. will it be okay?

Answer (score 0):

The command from command line to track usage is `top`

It will list your processes. You can start this on tty1 and check it when you feel the system is getting slow. The top processes in the list are the processes that consume the most from your system.

Example:

```
top - 11:38:07 up 66 days, 16:25, 162 users,  load average: 2.47, 2.61, 2.59
Tasks: 311 total,   9 running, 302 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  4.7%us,  9.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 86.1%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  16451368k total, 16204556k used,   246812k free,   224064k buffers
Swap: 16761852k total,  1360184k used, 15401668k free,  3471096k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
29563 xxxxxx    20   0 17812 2916 1344 R  100  0.0   9183:26 xxx
21109 xxxxxx    20   0 17668 2544 1348 S   35  0.0   7699:15 xxx
 1519 xxxxxx    20   0  9152 1404 1056 S    8  0.0   7884:35 xxx
23193 compram   20   0 21592 1544 1008 R    1  0.0   0:00.03 top
   16 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0  85:56.21 ksoftirqd/3
   22 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0  63:16.01 ksoftirqd/5
   34 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0  20:51.27 ksoftirqd/9
```

Comment: okay but i heard ubuntu is very fast. even RAM is low . my friend says . it is very slow why?.

Comment: if increase 4GB to 6 GB. will it be okay?

Comment: Who lied about that to you? Ubuntu is just like any other OS. The -hardware- is what makes it fast. My system installs Linux in under 20 minutes and boots in 9 seconds (well that's me counting seconds ;-) ).  But that's because of the ssd. So hardware. "if increase 4GB to 6 GB. will it be okay?" Doubt it. Your CPU and harddisk (ssd/hdd) are more important.

Comment: what do you mean ssd?